# Make a particular text in textarea to be bold

Tags: c#, html, razor, model-view-controller

I have 2 notes which are displayed in the textarea of a table.
There are 2 headings associated with the 2 notes. However i have to make the headings bold and make the second heading fall in the next line.

```
<td> 
    <textarea name="txtarea" id="txtid" style="border:none; min-width:200px ; min-height : 250px; "> Organisation Notes : @Model.SendMailList[i].OrgNotes @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.SendMailList[i].OrgNotes )  
                User Notes :   @Model.SendMailList[i].UserNotes @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.SendMailList[i].UserNotes )
          </textarea>                        
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use HTML inside TEXTAREA.

Instead you can emulate it:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.editable').each(function(){
    this.contentEditable = true;
  });;
});
```

```css
div.editable {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
}
.go {
   font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML

<table width="100%">
<tr><th>HEADER 1</th><th>HEADER 2</th></tr>
<tr><td>OTHER TEXT</td><td><div class="editable"><p class="go">Organisation Notes :</p>  <p> @Model.SendMailList[i].OrgNotes @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.SendMailList[i].OrgNotes )</p> <p class="go">User Notes :</p><p> @Model.SendMailList[i].UserNotes @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.SendMailList[i].UserNotes )</p> </div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Regards

Comment: I did this .. But the textarea is not resizeable.. It appears to be fixed..

Comment: Fixed, i forgot about that. Now is working, just add jquery and the jquery snippet

Comment: @Sansa_Winterfell Did it work? If so, please mark the answer as correct